# Access key/ keyboard shortcut doesn't work after I added the accesskey attribute. Why is that?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, access-keys

We are only concerned with the following snippet:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a accesskey="s" href="#student-info">INFO</a></li>
      <li><a accesskey="h" href="#html-questions">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a accesskey="c" href="#css-questions">CSS</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I added the access keys/ shortcuts s, h, and, c to the three list items in our navigation bar. However, when I press s, h, or c, nothing happens. Isn't something supposed to happen? To elaborate, in the output, if I click on any of INFO, HTML, and CSS in the navigation bar, I will go straight to that section. Similarly, shouldn't the same thing happen if I press 's' instead of clicking on INFO in the navigation bar?

**Disclaimer:** Just ignore the CSS file. We are only concerned with the accesskey attribute in the anchor elements nested in the nav element.

These are my html and css files:

```css
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  * {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
}

body {
  background: #f5f6f7;
  color: #1b1b32;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #1b1b32;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#logo {
  width: max(100px, 18vw);
  background-color: #0a0a23;
  aspect-ratio: 35 / 4;
  padding: 0.4rem;
}

h1 {
  color: #f1be32;
    font-size: min(5vw, 1.2em);
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  margin-block: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

nav > ul > li {
  color: #dfdfe2;
  margin: 0 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  display: block;
}

nav > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: #dfdfe2;
  color: #1b1b32;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

main {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

section {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma;
}

h2 {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #dfdfe2;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.info {
  padding: 10px 0 0 5px;
}

.formrow {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

input {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.info label, .info input {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

.info input {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}

.info label {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 55px;
}

.question-block {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p::before {
  content: "Question #";
}

.question {
  border: none;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.answers-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
    display: block;
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 23px;
    background: #d0d0d5;
    border: 3px solid #3b3b4f;
}

footer {
    background-color: #2a2a40;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

footer,
footer a {
  color: #dfdfe2;
}

address {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="freeCodeCamp Accessibility Quiz practice project" />
    <title>Accessibility Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img id="logo" src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/platform/universal/fcc_primary.svg">
      <h1>HTML/CSS Quiz</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a accesskey="s" href="#student-info">INFO</a></li>
          <li><a accesskey="h" href="#html-questions">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a accesskey="c" href="#css-questions">CSS</a></li>
              </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <form method="post" action="https://freecodecamp.org/practice-project/accessibility-quiz">
        <section role="region" aria-labelledby="student-info">
          <h2 id="student-info">Student Info</h2>
          <div class="info">
            <label for="student-name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="student-name" id="student-name" />
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <label for="student-email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="student-email" id="student-email" />
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <label for="birth-date">D.O.B.<span class="sr-only">(Date of Birth)</span></label>
            <input type="date" name="birth-date" id="birth-date" />
          </div>
        </section>
        <section role="region" aria-labelledby="html-questions">
          <h2 id="html-questions">HTML</h2>
          <div class="question-block">
            <p>1</p>
            <fieldset class="question" name="html-question-one">
              <legend>
                The legend element represents a caption for the content of its
                parent fieldset element
              </legend>
              <ul class="answers-list">
                <li>
                  <label for="q1-a1">
                    <input type="radio" id="q1-a1" name="q1" value="true" />
                    True
                  </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <label for="q1-a2">
                    <input type="radio" id="q1-a2" name="q1" value="false" />
                    False
                  </label>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div class="question-block">
            <p>2</p>
            <fieldset class="question" name="html-question-two">
              <legend>
                A label element nesting an input element is required to have a
                for attribute with the same value as the input's id
              </legend>
              <ul class="answers-list">
                <li>
                  <label for="q2-a1">
                    <input type="radio" id="q2-a1" name="q2" value="true" />
                    True
                  </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <label for="q2-a2">
                    <input type="radio" id="q2-a2" name="q2" value="false" />
                    False
                  </label>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section role="region" aria-labelledby="css-questions">
          <h2 id="css-questions">CSS</h2>
          <div class="formrow">
            <div class="question-block">
              <label for="customer">Are you a frontend developer?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer">
              <select name="customer" id="customer" required>
                <option value="">Select an option</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="question-block">
              <label for="css-questions">Do you have any questions:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="answer">
              <textarea id="css-questions" name="css-questions" rows="5" cols="24" placeholder="Who is flexbox..."></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <address>
        <a href="https://freecodecamp.org">freeCodeCamp</a><br />
        San Francisco<br />
        California<br />
        USA
      </address>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using accesskeys is difficult because they may conflict with other key standards in the browser.

To avoid this problem, most browsers will use accesskeys only if pressed together with the Alt key.

Reference - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp

Comment: The combinations of keys that you have to press vary with browser.This link has a table showing them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work, but [it depends on the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey) which combination is necessary to activate the access key.

Single characters keys are not a good idea, since they conflict with controls for the browser and screen readers. Hence, browsers typically require a key combination:

On Windows, it’s most likely <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>*key*</kbd>

And on Mac <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>*key*</kbd>

In general, there are some accessibility caveats with the `accesskey` attribute. See [Accesskey on WebAIM](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey)

> Due to numerous problems with implementation, accesskey is typically best avoided.

For some discussion on how to communicate the access keys to sighted users, see [How to highlight accesskeys in a WCAG valid way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72299819/how-to-highlight-accesskeys-in-a-wcag-valid-way/72351843#72351843)